# Ruby-on-rails Как расширить таблицу

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Пытаюсь сделать список с возможностью создавать категории и вкладывать туда задания.

Но не могу понять, как добавлять больше одного `description` в `title`?

**миграция:**

```
class CreateTodos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :todos do |t|  
      t.string :title
      t.string :description
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Контроллер**

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController

   def index
    @todos = Todo.all
    @todo = Todo.new

  end


def create
    @todo = Todo.create todo_params
    redirect_to todo_path(@todo)
end

def edit
  @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
end

def show
 @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
    Todo.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end

def update

    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    @todo.update todo_params
    redirect_to todo_path(@todo)
end



private
    def todo_params
      params.require(:todo).permit(:title, :description)
    end

end
```

**страница**

```
<h1>Создать категорию</h2>


<%= form_for @todo do |f| %>
<%= label_tag(:title, "Категория:") %></br>
<%= f.text_field :title %></br>
<input type="submit" value="Создать">
<% end %>
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</br>
<% @todos.each do |todo| %>

     <B><font size="5"> <%=  todo.title %></font></B>     

      <%= link_to " x", todo, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }%></br>

<li><%= todo.description%></li>

<% end %>

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<h1>Добавить задачу</h1>


<%= form_for @todo do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :description %></br>

<select required>
    <% @todos.each do |todo| %>    
         <option><%=  todo.title %></option>  
    <%end%>
</select> 


<input type="submit" value="Добавить">



<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - вынести description в отдельную таблицу и организовать между ними связь один-ко-многим.